# Binding do Facebook SDK 3.6 para Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, facebook, xamarin.android

No meu projeto com o Xamarin, preciso utilizar o *binding* do Facebook SDK para Android na versão 3.6. Porém, só consegui encontrar o [binding da versão 3.0](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/Facebook), que está defasado.

Alguém sabe onde posso encontrar o Binding do Facebook SDK para Android na versão 3.6, ou como adaptar o que encontrei para o SDK mais novo? Existe alguma outra alternativa?

Comment: Você pode ser mais específico quanto a quais recursos você precisa? Você tentou seguir as instruções do README desse link que você passou, mas com o zip do SDK mais novo? O que aconteceu, deu erro?

Comment: Creio que com a resposta e o comentário do autor na resposta já ficou mais claro o que ele precisava. Podemos reabrir a questão e deixá-la com a resposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Há algumas alternativas para você usar:

### Alternativa 1 - Usar o MonoDroid-Samples do Facebook

Você pode simplesmente seguir os passos dados pela página que você mesmo referenciou:

1. Fazer o download do SDK clicando [aqui](https://www.facebook.com/campaign/landing.php?campaign_id=282184128580929&placement=Android_SDK&url=https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-android-sdk-current.zip)
2. Extrair o `ZIP`
3. Ir para a pasta `facebook`
4. Rodar `android update project -p .`
5. Rodar `ant debug`
6. Rodar `zip -r facebook-android-sdk.zip bin/classes.jar bin/AndroidManifest.xml res`
7. Copiar o arquivo `facebook-android-sdk.zip` para a pasta Jars do seu projeto

### Alternativa 2 - Usar o coponente da Xamarin Store

Há vários componentes:

- O [Facebook SDK](https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebook-sdk), que usa o projeto [Facebook SDK for .NET](http://facebooksdk.net)
- O [Xamarin.Social](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.social) que atua com o Facebook, Twitter, App.net e Flickr
- O [Parse](https://components.xamarin.com/view/parse) que é uma empresa disponibiliza uma API Social e foi comprada pelo Facebook
- O [Xamarin.Auth](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.auth)  que permite autenticação pelo Facebook

### Alternativa 3 - Usar o SDK do Facebook para .NET

Esse projeto pode ser encontrado [aqui](http://facebooksdk.net), tem seu código aberto e é recomendado para o uso no Windows 8 e Windows Phone, além de funcionar no Mono/Xamarin

Comment: Alexandre, obrigado pela resposta, realizei o procedimento de compilar a versão nova no SKD usando os procedimentos do Binding Antigo e funcionou em partes, alguns recursos funcionam e outros não. Na própria compilação do projeto binding dá alguns erros mas gera a DLL. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @user1271442 você não pode disponibilizar esta lib que você criou no github ou por email? julio.turolla@gmail.com

Comment: @JúlioTurollaRibeiro é a mesma que eu fiz referência [aqui](https://www.facebook.com/campaign/landing.php?campaign_id=282184128580929&placement=Android_SDK&url=https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-android-sdk-current.zip) e [aqui](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/Facebook)

Comment: Não tem um binding pronto? O link do facebook é o SKD normal, o do github está desatualizadissimo.

Comment: @JúlioTurollaRibeiro, tem que seguir os passoas da alternativa 1 que eu citei aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2260/280